# PayPal unsubscribe button for specific subscription identifier

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have created this unsubscribe button.

```
<A HREF="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_subscr-find&alias=RXXXXXXXXX">
    <IMG SRC="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_unsubscribe_LG.gif" BORDER="0">
</A>
```

The problem is that if the user has more than one subscriptions, PayPal will display a message:

> To cancel a specific subscription click on its details. This will take
>   you to its details page where you will find a Cancel button."` instead
>   of taking the user to the specific subscription.

How can I extend this button to include the specific subscription id so that it navigates directly to the correct subscription instead of just displaying a list of various transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the HTML Unsubscribe button no, but PayPal has an API called `ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus` that allows you to cancel specific profiles through your website. It's a more complicated integration but can eliminate potential confusion for your customers.

Below are the parameters required for the API call

```
USER=
PWD=
SIGNATURE=
METHOD=ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus
VERSION=98.0
PROFILEID=Profile ID here
ACTION=Cancel
```

This also means you'll have to track your customer's profile IDs along with the status of their profile(s).